# content of a node's publications

Tags: ros, transforms, messages, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am playing around with the navigation stack and turtlebot and trying to debug the errors I get. Especially the topic /tf where many nodes are publishing transformations. How to know from which node is which transformation? Is there something like rostopic echo that allows to echo nodes coming from a preselected node?

When I run `rosrun tf tf_monitor` all I get is :

> Frame: pole_middle_3_link published by
> unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.5
> Max Delay: 0

for all published transforms.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193356/content-of-a-node%27s-publications/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-09-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-09-24**:
I remember that there's somewhere the information about the publisher in the message, but don't remember the exact name or position of it. This has been asked a several time here. All answers said that this information should only be used to debug. I don't think `rostopic` can do that.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-09-24**:
any suggestion about keywords to search about old questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the link: http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Connection_Information

You have to write your own little node that prints the publishers.

Please note the comment on this site:

> We do not recommend using callerid information beyond debugging purposes, as it can lead to brittle code in an anonymous publish/subscribe architecture.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-09-24**:
yes it is just for debugging, thanks :)